# Crear un nuevo objeto en base al resultado de otras funciones

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs

Realizo algunas operaciones desde un `array multidimensional` y las funciones me retornan objetos `array de objetos`.

`ordersDispach()`:

```
Promise {
  [
    {
      '1': null,
      '2835889': 1,
      '2846705': 1,
      '2869563': 1,
      '3006434': 1
    },
    { '1': null, '2836187': 1, '2870201': 1, '2872035': 1 }
  ]
}
```

Y la función `timer()` retorna:

```
Promise {
  [
    {
      '1': '0min',
      '2835889': '10min',
      '2846705': '10min',
      '2869563': '10min',
      '3006434': '10min'
    },
    {
      '1': '0min',
      '2836187': '10min',
      '2870201': '10min',
      '2872035': '10min'
    }
  ]
}
```

Ahora estoy intentando retornar un nuevo objeto, que contenga las propiedades de ambos mandandolos a ejecutar en una misma función, no sé si esta sea la mejor manera, pero agradecería de sus ayuda.

```
const ordersDispached = async disp => disp.map(e => e.stops.reduce((acc, e2) => ({ ...acc, [e2.siteId]: e2.numberOfOrders }), {}))

const timerService = async disp => disp.map(e => e.stops.reduce((acc, e2) => ({ ...acc, [e2.siteId]: `${e2.numberOfOrders * 10}min` }), {}))

    const mergeObjets = async(disp) => {
  try{
    let obj1 = await ordersDispached(disp).then(r=>r).catch(e=>e)
    let obj2 = await timerServiceByStops(disp).then(r=>r).catch(e=>e)
    var obj = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)
    console.log(obj)
  }
  catch(e){
    console.error(e)
  }
}

console.log(mergeObjets(disp, sites))
```

Pero esto me retorna el error de `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined` y no entiendo por que arrays, que le inyecto a las funciones hijas para luego llamarlas en el mergeObjects inyectando estos mismo arrays

```
sites = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "distribution-center",
        "openTime": null,
        "closeTime": null
}];
disp = const disp = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "startTime": "08:55",
        "stops": [
            {
                "siteId": 1,
                "sequence": 1,
                "numberOfOrders": null
            }]
    }];
```

Comment: En qué parte del código estás obteniendo el error?

Comment: @AndresGardiol en la linea de la funcion timerService

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y aclara eso. Además agrega qué forma tienen o de donde salen los parármetros `disp` y `sites`. Es decir, cómo llamas a `mergeObjets`. Por último, agrega TODO el código pertinente al problema

Comment: @AndresGardiol gracias por tu comentario, pregunta editada

Answer (score 1):

> Pero esto me retorna el error de `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

La función `timerService` está intentando acceder a la propiedad `stops` de cada item dentro del arreglo recibido por el parámetro:

```javascript
const timerService = async disp => 
  disp.map(e => e.stops.reduce((acc, e2) => // e.stops.reduce
     ({ ...acc, [e2.siteId]: `${e2.numberOfOrders * 10}min` }), {}))
```

El problema está en `mergeObjets`:

```javascript
const mergeObjets = async(disp, sites) => {
  try{
    let obj1 = await ordersDispached(disp)
    let obj2 = await timerService(sites) // Estas enviando el arreglo sites
    newObj = {...obj1, obj2}
    console.log(newObj)
  }
  catch(e){
    console.error(e)
  }
}
console.log(mergeObjets(disp, sites))
```

Estás enviándole a la función `timerService()` el arreglo `sites`. Y según compartiste, el arreglo sites no tiene objetos con la propiedad `stops`:

```javascript
sites = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "distribution-center",
        "openTime": null,
        "closeTime": null
    }
];
```

Tienes 2 opciones para solucionar el error, que dependen de tu aplicación.

1. Agregar la propiedad `stops` a los objetos del arreglo `sites`
2. Enviar el arreglo `disp` a la función `timerService`

Comment: Si mira edite la pregunta, donde puse como estoy llamando las funciones asyncronas, me ejecuta solo la segunda funcion. La primera me manda "pending", que puedo hacer?

Comment: Pues agrega lo que obtienes en la pregunta o crea un ejemplo minimo reproducible para poder ayudarte https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Si ya lo edite con, intentado resolver las promesas en la funcion mergeObject

Comment: Perdón pero sigo viendo que en la pregunta mencionas que tienes el error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined ` no veo el nuevo error que tienes.